# Subsetting data frame based on frequency

Tags: r

I've been trying to figure out this problem for some time now. I have the following data frame with repeated observation by ID:

```
ID  color
1   blue
1   red
1   blue
2   red
2   blue
2   red
.
.
.
```

I want to create a new data frame by choosing the color with the highest frequency for each ID so that I have only 1 row for each ID. That is, I'd like to get the following data frame:

```
ID  color
1   blue
2   red
3
.
.
.
```

I attempted using `transform` but that didn't work as it only summed the number of times each ID appeared in the data.
`transform(df, freq.ID = ave(seq(nrow(df)), ID, FUN=length))`

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the frequency count based on 'ID', 'color', creates a summarised 'n' column with frequency, then do order the rows on the 'ID' and `desc`ending order of 'n', and use the `distinct` to return the first unique row for each 'ID'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  count(ID, color) %>%
  arrange(ID, desc(n)) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

-output

```
#   ID color
#1  1  blue
#2  2   red
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), color = c("blue", 
"red", "blue", "red", "blue", "red")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R method using `aggregate` and `ave` -

```
subset(aggregate(length~color + ID, transform(df1, length = ID), length), 
     ave(length, ID, FUN = function(x) x == max(x)) == 1)

#  color ID length
#1  blue  1      2
#4   red  2      2
```